# SMPP TLV optional parameters

Tags: smpp, tlv

I'm new to SMPP protocol. I'm using it for sending SMS via SMSC.
I found in docs that it is possible to send optional TLV parameters.

I want to send `additional_status_info_text` in `submit_sm` and receve it back in `deliver_sm.` Is it by spec of SMPP or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure, but I don't think it is by spec. I remember `additional_status_info_text` being used mostly to send extra information, like for debugging purposes.

You want to receive in the `deliver_sm` with the delivery receipt for your `submit_sm` the info you sent in the TLV or ?

Maybe if you could give more details about what you are trying to achieve exactly with the return of that parameter, I could be of more help.

Comment: I've just contacted with SMSC provider and they confirm that additional_status_info_text is sent back. Any way thanks for an answer)